Unit testing Angular 17 models
I have a component with a required model. How do I unit test that the value has been updated?
import { Component, model } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myModel">`
  standalone: true,
})
export class BooleanToggler {
  readonly myModel = model.required<boolean>();
}

I can set the value of the model with fixture.componentRef.setInput('myModel', true). I can toggle the checkbox with (fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelector('input')!.click(). However, this does not trigger an update to myModel, and I cannot spy on the emitter with spyOn(fixture.componentInstance.myModel, 'emit'), as I would with an @Output(), as emit does not exist on ModelSignal. spyOn(fixture.componentInstance.myModel, 'set') also does not work.

Why not directly check the myModel value for the update ?

@MatthieuRiegler thank you! That does indeed work: the problem was that I hadn’t imported FormsModule, so my model wasn’t being updated properly at all. I was wrongly thinking that it was the fault of the model function.
